# How to get data value from bookstrap dropdown-menu so I can pass to database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I am making a to-do list with HTML, CSS, Javascript, jQuery, node.js, SQL(postgres), express, and pool. I have a user input form for the task name and a priority-status, displayed as a bootstrap drop down in my HTML, shown here:

```
<form id="userInputs">
            
            <div>
            <input type="text" id="note" value="" maxlength="200" placeholder="Add a New Note...">
            </div>
            
            <div class="userButttons">
                
                    <button id="priorityStatus" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    When do you Need to Do it?</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <option class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="now">NOW</option>
                        <option class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="soonish"">Soon-ish</option>
                        <option class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="later">Later</option>
                    </div>
                
                <button id="addBtn" class="btn btn-secondary">Add</button>
            
            </div>

        </form>
```

I am attempting to get the data value of one of the options, so I can pass that those two things as an object in my POST request to the server, shown here in my client.js:

```
$(document).ready(readyNow);

function readyNow(){
    console.log('jQuery is working, it is safe to manipulate the DOM');
    // ⬇ Establish click listeners
    clickListeners();
    // ⬇ Load existing tasks on page load:
    refreshTasks();
} // end readyNow function

function clickListeners(){
    console.log('in clickListeners function');
    // ⬇ click listener for the addBtn
    $( '#addBtn' ).on('click', addTask);
    // ⬇ Click listener dropdown
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    // $('.dropdown-item').dropdown('update');
}

function addTask(){
    console.log('in addTask function');
    // ⬇ Grabbing the user's input
    let task = {
        task: $('#note').val(),
        status: //! I need the status to go here!!!!!!
    // ⬇ Testing that I can get the task on client side - I can!
    console.log(task);
    // ⬇ Sending the input to the server
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/todo',
        data: task
    }).then( response => {
        console.log(`Your task has been added`, response);
        // ⬇ Emptying the user input fields
        $('input').val('');
        // ⬇ Will refresh the DOM with the updated database containing the new information
        refreshTasks()
    })
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. Any advice?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `click` event on dropdown-item . So ,whenever your option gets clicked just add some class to that option just to  know that it is selected . Then , inside  `addTask` function get status value using `$(".dropdown-item.selected").data("value")` and pass same to ajax.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function addTask() {
  console.log('in addTask function');
  //to get status:
  var status = $(".dropdown-item.selected").data("value")
  console.log("status --" + status)

  //ajax call

}
//onclick of dropdown-item..
$(".dropdown-item").on("click", function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected") //remove from others
  $(this).addClass("selected") //add slected to the one which clicked
  console.log($(".dropdown-item.selected").data("value"))

})
$('#addBtn').on('click', addTask);
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="userInputs">

  <div>
    <input type="text" id="note" value="" maxlength="200" placeholder="Add a New Note...">
  </div>

  <div class="userButttons">

    <button id="priorityStatus" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    When do you Need to Do it?</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="now">NOW</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="soonish">Soon-ish</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="# " data-value="later">Later</option>
    </div>


    <button type="button" id="addBtn" class="btn btn-secondary ">Add</button>

  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: This works PERFECTLY! Thank you for the clear explanation of what I was missing and how I could approach the problem differently.